# MUI X DataGridPro not rendering cellValue when column has valueOptions prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui-x-data-grid

I have MUI X DataGrid Pro with column:

```
{
  field: "productCategoryName",
  headerName: "Category",
  flex: 2,
},
```

Everything works well without valueOptions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD8Ia.png)

Category is showing.

But when I add valueOptions:

```
{
  field: "productCategoryName",
  headerName: "Category",
  flex: 2,
  type: "singleSelect",
  valueOptions: [
    { label: "Test", value: "guid" },
    { label: "Test Category 2", value: "guid2" },
  ],
},
```

cellValue disappears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvyh3.png)

I have tried with valueOptions without value and that is also works fine, but I need it's to be an obejct:

```
{
  field: "productCategoryName",
  headerName: "Category",
  flex: 2,
  type: "singleSelect",
  valueOptions: ["Test", "Test2"],
},
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y9r0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auKx2.png)

Comment: Found bug. I passed to productCategoryName actual name, but I need to provide its id like id in valueOptions.